# Bid vs ask if spreads are wide or narrow

Tags: stocks

In a bid vs ask if it has a large spread does this indicate that it is harder to get what you paid for it back in return or say the market price? Or can you always get the market sale if the price is up. If that makes sense.

Comment: Welcome new user.   Many questions on here about the basic confusion with **thin markets**.  Trading a thin market (like when you buy and sell a house) is dramatically different from trading the world's 100 or so largest sticks, which have huge volume, **and falsely give you the impression that there "is" a price**.

Answer (score 2):

A large spread in normal market conditions is an indication of low liquidity. This means that it will be hard to get the price you want buying in and hard to get the price you want again selling out.

If the spread is large on a continuous basis and there are few trades each day with relatively low volume, stay away, this is a certainty for losing money.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trading at market quotes, you buy at the ask price and you sell at the bid price.  The difference between the two is the spread.  In order to break even, the security must move up by the amount of the spread.

The wider the spread, the less liquid the security is.

Answer (score -2):

When you participate in the market, you can be either a "market maker" or a "market taker". When you're a "market maker", you submit a offer to buy or sell at a particular price, and wait for someone to take you up on it. When you're a market taker, you look for someone who's already made an offer, and take them up on it. The benefit of being a market maker is that you can submit an offer for any price you want; the drawback is that there's no guarantee that anyone will take you up on it (and if they do, it's quite possibly because the market is moving against you). Conversely, if you're a market taker, you've guaranteed a trade (assuming someone else doesn't get to the offer before you, or the offer isn't rescinded), but the drawback is that the other party gets to set the price; it's a take-it-or-leave-it situation.

If you buy and sell as a market taker, then you'll be buying at the ask price and selling at the bid price, so a large spread means that you're losing a lot of money (although if you hold the stock for a long time, the appreciation of the stock usually is more than enough to cover the difference). The other option is to be a market maker, in which case you'll have to sit around waiting for your order to be filled (and it may never be filled). So if you're willing to buy a stock knowing that it may take a while to offload it, a large bid-ask spread isn't as big a deal.

Another issue with a spread, however, is that the market serves as a pricing mechanism. When you see bid-ask quotes, you know that the combined judgment of market participants says that the "right" price is between those two numbers. The efficient market hypothesis says that on average, this reflects the real value of the stock. So when the spread is small, you know within a small window what the fair market value of the stock is. But when the spread is large, the fair market value could be anything in between, so there's more uncertainty as to whether you're getting a good deal.

Comment: TYPO? "When you're a market maker, you look for someone who's already made an offer, and take them up on it."